# Reading strings and decreasing them

Tags: python

I just have a simple question when dealing with text files:
I have a text file and want to make a python program to read it and if it finds any number it replaces it by the number preceding it like if it finds 4 it replaces it with 3 so how can I do that?

The problem for me in this program is that python reads the numbers as strings, not integers, so it can't decrease or increase them.

```
 out = open("out.txt", "w")
with open("Spider-Man.Homecoming.2017.1080p.BluRay.x264-[YTS.AG].txt", "r") as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        if line.isdigit():
            out.write(str(int(line - 1)))
        else:
            out.write(line)
```

This code doesn't detect the numbers as numbers and I don't know why.

Comment: You can check each character and replace it accordingly if `character.isnum()` is `True`

Comment: try: `''.join(str(int(c)-1) if c.isdigit() else c for c in "123foobar")`

Comment: You can convert a string into an integer using the [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) class.

Comment: I added the code so you can check it

Comment: Do you expect to have numbers larger than 9? If so, the given solution would not be valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting @Samwise's comment together with your code:

```
with open("Spider-Man.Homecoming.2017.1080p.BluRay.x264-[YTS.AG].txt", "r") as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    new_lines = []
    for line in lines:
        decreased = ''.join(str(int(c)-1) if c.isdigit() else c for c in line)
        new_lines.append(decreased)

with open('out.txt', 'w') as out:
    out.writelines(new_lines)
```

You also should close the file after writing to it, so switched to `with open` at the end as a better way to write to file.

Comment: I can't understand this part "if c.isdigit() else c for c in line)" could you please simplify it?

Comment: In English: If c is a digit, then give me c-1. Otherwise give me c. Do that for all individual characters in the line.